# BI Publisher 11g hide pivot table header

Tags: bi-publisher

is there a way to hide the bi publisher RTF template pivot table header (in 11g)?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the pivot table header by setting the header font, margin and padding to 0.